# Is there a benefit of running a 1in pipe off a 3/4 pipe for irrigation

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, water-pressure, irrigation

I have a 3/4 in. pex water line coming out of my meter to my house. I would like "T" that line and run a 1 in. pipe (or larger) off it. My question is, will I see an increase in flow in the larger pipe since the water is already traveling thought a 3/4 in pipe? I would like more pressure/flow so I can run my larger sprinklers.

Comment: Does [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62133/is-there-any-benefit-to-upsizing-to-3-4-pipe-off-a-1-2-main-supply) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

No, running a bigger pipe won’t increase the supply pressure or flow, those losses have already occurred.

But, when you upgrade the supply **then** that 1" pipe will pay off.

Increasing the diameter will reduce the velocity and therefore the losses.

Comment: Put another way, what what happens if I hook a 1in hose up to a spigot supplied by a 3/4 in. line?

Comment: @bmass120 water will flow. But slower in the larger pipe, however the mass flow rate will be constant. The diameter difference governs the velocity change.

Comment: So would my sprinkler spray more water further?

Answer (score 0):

As "benefit" you are thinking of more flow and or pressure.

That will not happen, since flow and pressure are already regulated in the supply line (3/4 inch).

However, you might experience a pressure drop.

The distance for the sprinkler depends on sprinkler design and incommoding pressure.

You can make it spray further by reducing the nozzle size.

Comment: Interesting.. at the end of the day I just want my sprinkler to spray more water further and possibly have the ability to run 2 or more at the same time.

Comment: @bmass120 pressure pushes the flow, What is your home incoming pressure ? You can increase the flow by increasing the pressure.

Comment: pressure is about 70 psi.

Comment: @bmass120 that would be sufficient pressure. Try another sprinkler head with smaller nozzles.

Answer (score 0):

If the line from the meter to the valve box is long, the line will reduce flow and pressure somewhat.  A larger line will reduce it less.  Whether it's enough to matter is hard to predict.   In my area installers always use 1 inch from meter to valve box.  Nobody has a 1 inch meter.  I don't know why 1 inch is used but on a fixed price irrigation install I assume it gets the installer better results.